# Communicating with interactive program?

Tags: ruby

I want to run the command:

```
svn ls --username xxx
```

from a script. It requests a password so I have to pass the password to it.  How I can do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent writeup about using the SVN Ruby bindings:

[Using Subversion Ruby Bindings](http://blog.carlossanchez.eu/2009/08/18/using-subversion-ruby-bindings/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
require 'open3'

username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"

Open3.popen3("svn ls --username #{username}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.puts(password)
  stdin.close
end
```

This comes straight out of my head, I haven't tested it so it might break in horrible ways. ;)

Comment: Your script doesn't show that it works. I've added a line "puts stdout.getc" after "stdin.close". Now the script stops to prompt a password. It seems that svn creates new tty for a password prompt, so stdin.puts can't work

Comment: Try putting `puts stdout.gets` before `stdin.close`